# Centering the focused item in nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, focus

I'm creating an Android app for use on my Android TV and phone to view my personally stored media, i am trying to get a layout similar to the Netflix app and have the UI mostly complete however when i navigate the app using D'Pad controls the item with focus does not center vertically. Is there a way to force this behavior through the layout files?

activity_main

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="activity.MainActivity">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="740dp"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/genre_recycler"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

genre_unit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Genre.Title"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/genre_inner_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/genre_heading"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

genre_inner_unit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/genre_movie_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre_movie_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/genre_movie_image"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/genre_movie_image"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/genre_movie_image"
        android:text="Movie Title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do it from the XML layout, however you could take a look at the `LinearSnapHelper` class that comes with `RecyclerView`. If that particular one does not fit your needs, you can create your own version by extending the `SnapHelper` class.

Comment: Thank you your a star, for anyone else looking for a solution this link is straight forward. https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8